# jstree node styling

Tags: css, stylesheet, styling, jstree

I'm trying to style a specific node in my jsTree.

I want to change the icon of the node above my leaf!

This line styles my leaf and now I need to go one level higher.

```
.jstree-classic .jstree-leaf a ins.jstree-icon { background: url(../../images/File.ico) 0 0 no-repeat; }
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used [Types Plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types) where each type can have their own icon. Does answer your question?

If not could you provide jsfiddle sample? Something like http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/

Comment: Yes, i made it with the Types plugin now.
The only problem i had doing this was to add the concrete type to the json object because i did it in the wrong place of the mvc model.
But it's working :)